# IIS 7.5 - different file size for same compressed file served from two different servers

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, compression

I'm facing the problem that our lengthy CSS file (`129 KB`) gets delivered by our ASP.NET web app (running on IIS 7.5 using .NET 4.0) compressed to `24 KB` on my local server machine and `36 KB` on both our staging and production sites. My local OS is Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise, the web servers run Windows Web Server 2008 R2.

I used the [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) to look into the requests but they seem not to differ in anything important, i.e. `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` is sent to all servers and all reply with `Content-Encoding: gzip`. All have static and dynamic compression enabled.

Does anybody have **any idea** what could be causing the difference in behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Scott Forsyth's blog entry](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2009/02/22/iis-7-compression-good-bad-how-much.aspx) on compression... it's a great one.  Most importantly, there are several compression levels that can be set and may be different between your servers.  You can check out more at the IIS.net site on [httpCompression](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpCompression/scheme).

-Chris

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the different compression levels! Will check it out in detail but for now your answer put me on the right track, I guess.